# Mathematical notation for a function that returns reals but I want to return the integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, notation

How can I modify this notation to denote the following? I want to describe a alternating series generated by taking **sin**(n) and filtering out all but the integers so that if the domain is **R**, the resulting series is {1,0,-1,1,0,-1...} .

[image: m]

Comment: I don't think the sine function is the best tool for doing what you seem to want to do.

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sin(n\pi/2)\ ?$$

Answer (score 1):

It's common to put a condition under the sum to denote the $n$'s to be used in the summation so you could write something along the lines of:

$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and }\sin(n) \in \mathbb{Z}} \sin(n).$$

Not sure if this is what you're going after?

Comment: It's worth warning that this is uncommon, and might be ambiguous in some cases. Something like $\sum_{\substack{n\in \mathbb R>0\\ \sin(n)\in \mathbb Z}}\frac{\sin(n)}n$ is harder to interpret - it might be shorthand for $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{\substack{n\in (0,x) \\ \sin(n)\in\mathbb Z}}\frac{\sin(n)}n$$ which converges, or it might be asking for a measure theoretic sum, which diverges.